# 70's book, man wakes up from hibernation in a wasteland, participates in tournaments used by aliens to pick their slaves

Tags: story-identification, books

I first read this book in the 70's.

A man loses wife and kid(s?), buys land in middle of nowhere, builds underground bunker, goes into hibernation, wakes up; the world is now a wasteland. He finds a military bunker built on top of his, finds armour, gets attacked by rats, the armour suit saves him.

He rescues a local, join clans, wins fighting tournament that gives him a place to go to big tournament at gods mountain(?). He meets humanoids from another planet who are using the tournament to find who can live on their planet to use as slaves.

The cover has a large vault door that has been chewed by rats with him standing in front with a rifle and you can see rats all around.

Comment: It is also searched for here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/217065/science-fiction-novel-from-the-70s-i-think-about-a-cryogenically-suspended-ma#comment615838_217065

Answer (score 8):

[*Star Gods*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9721285-star-gods) (1978) by Jack Lovejoy

> When his wife and son are killed in a freak auto accident, professor Glenn Randolf looks to the future for a better world. He proves his theory of induced hibernation by placing himself in his own invention, a time capsule, and falls into a 375 year sleep.
>
> Randolf awakes to the horrors of a barren land populated by savage mutants, but finds his way to an oasis called "The Holy City" where a beautiful society of humans live and practice a religion devoted to gods from the stars - aliens who are sapping the genes of the strongest humans to strengthen their own civilization. Randolf is forced to use every ounce of physical power and cunning to save his life...and the community of beautiful Earth people from extinction.

[image: yellowish book cover, man in front of round entrance, battling rats]

Comment: Jenayah did you answer my post and identify this book ????? how the hell did you remember it ??

Comment: Oh Ayshe, I think the OP got confused by the UI and mistook me for the answerer. I can't answer the question of how the answer was found, but maybe you can, if you remember your thought process/search query/whatever. I'm curious as well :)

Comment: I haven't read it, I can't remember exactly how I found it, I think I used worldcat.org's advanced search with "science fiction" and "hibernation" keywords.