# Science Fiction Novel from the 70's (I think) about a cryogenically suspended man who awakes in the far future

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember a novel I read ages ago and am looking for its name.

The story starts with the death of our characters wife and he cannot get over it.
So he sells everything and buys some land and builds a vault so he can put himself into suspended animation for 50 years. He believes that if the world has moved on maybe he can as well. Everything reminds him of her.
The vault is equipped with medical equipment and computers to reanimate and rehabilitate him when he awakes. It describes a long process of exercise etc to get him into shape so he can walk and eat again.
I particularly remember that the rats had almost eaten through the door by the time he was ready to leave. He finds he has been asleep for 5000 years
He then finds himself in a very different world and he goes on a quest to save the locals. 
Any help would be great!

Comment: He goes on a quest to save the locals from what? Was this a paperback? Remember anything about the cover?

Comment: I'd say it might the "The Man Who Awoke" by Laurence Manning but the only parts that seem to match up are the vault and being asleep for 5000-year periods. I feel I've heard of this story before, though.

Comment: Yes it was a paperback. I dont remember the cover. IM going back a lot of years. 70's novel. I keep thinking it was Children of the Gods or something similar but it doesnt come up anywhere. Thanks Space wolf but its not that one. It looks like an interesting read though.

Comment: I also remember they needed weapons and he found an 'ancients' vault of them, Clearly a reference to a missile silo or similar as they take about a great door with inscriptions mostly worn away.

Comment: It sounds like the book that is searched here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/book-i-first-read-in-the-70s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Book I first read in the 70's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/book-i-first-read-in-the-70s)

Comment: @Michael, they're only dupes if the answers are accepted, otherwise it's just speculation that they're the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Star Gods](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9721285-star-gods) by Jack Lovejoy

> When his wife and son are killed in a freak auto accident, professor
>   Glenn Randolf looks to the future for a better world. He proves his
>   theory of induced hibernation by placing himself in his own invention,
>   a time capsule, and falls into a 375 year sleep.
>
> Randolf awakes to the horrors of a barren land populated by savage
>   mutants, but finds his way to an oasis called "The Holy City" where a
>   beautiful society of humans live and practice a religion devoted to
>   gods from the stars - aliens who are sapping the genes of the
>   strongest humans to strengthen their own civilization. Randolf is
>   forced to use every ounce of physical power and cunning to save his
>   life...and the community of beautiful Earth people from extinction.

Comment: Thats the one! Thanks heaps for that! I really appreciate it. Now to find t for my kindle...